# Change Fragment in Navigation Drawer Activity (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

I've just started using **Fragments** and **ViewModels**. I want to replace fragments inside my activity, how can I do that?

What is the best approach to mix Android and Fragments together?

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    lateinit var fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        drawerLayout= findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_open)
            drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
            toggle.syncState()


        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_dersler, R.id.nav_soru,R.id.nav_socialmedia), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.nav_home -> {
                  //Toast.makeText(this,"Anasayfa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                R.id.nav_socialmedia -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Sosyal Medya Hesaplarımızı Takip Edebilirsiniz",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                R.id.nav_dersler -> {


                }
                R.id.nav_soru -> {

                }


            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            return true

        }


        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
            return true
        }




        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
             when(item.itemId){
                R.id.action_refresh -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Refreshing...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val refreshActivity = intent
                    finish()
                    startActivity(refreshActivity)
                    true
                }

                else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
            }
            return true
        }

        override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
            return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()

        }


}
```

And i have mobile_navigation.xml but i don't know what it does. Thank you for your help 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa0hK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:

`Activity` is your base component for making Screens in your app.
`Fragment` is a dynamic part of your screen which was added to support Tablets with bigger screens.

We usually combine them in these manners:

1. One Activity as a container and all the screens represented as `Fragment`s

For this approach, you can either

Implement it on your own:

Add fragments to your Activity stack:

```
supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .add(containerId, fragment, fragment::class.java.simpleName)
        .commit()
```

Replace fragments in your Activity:

```
supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(containerId, fragment, fragment::class.java.simpleName)
        .commit()
```

But Android introduces **Android Navigation Component** to handle all these add, replacement and back stack handling:

I suggest using this approach, as its the easier one. [LINK](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

2. Use multiple activities and fragments

For each screen that uses BottomNavigation, NavigationDrawer, and ... use an Activity with multiple Fragments representing each tab inside them.

A good tutorial can be found here. [LINK](https://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close)
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        //now i want to highLight the particular item that is clicked
        it.isChecked =true

        when (it.itemId) {

            R.id.nav_home -> replaceFragment(HomeFragment(),it.title.toString())

            R.id.nav_message ->  replaceFragment(MessageFragment(),it.title.toString())

        }
        true
    }
}
//when the user tab any icons the fragment will open. So, we create a Method
private fun replaceFragment(fragment : Fragment, title: String)
{
    //get the reference from the FragmentManager
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
    //whenEver user click on the drawer the drawer is closed
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
    setTitle(title)

}

//override method
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}}
```

Comment: if you have any problem then go to my git repo -https://github.com/anandrex5/NavigationDrawer_with_Fragment